# Is it possible to store variables in Azure Data Factory pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In my Azure Data Factory pipeline, I want to use a variable, which gets updated on each run and which is also read on each run. At the moment, I am using a Database to achieve that. But it would be much simpler if Azure Data Factory provided a way of storing variables. So, my question is, is there any such facility in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Do you mean [Set Variable activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) cannot meet your request(Variable update logic ) ?

Comment: @HarrisXu Can the value be passed to the next Pipeline run?

Comment: You can declare a parameter in PipelineB, when you executing PipelineB in PipelineA, you can pass the value form PipelineA variable to PipelineB parameter.

Comment: I want to use that variable for the same pipeline runs. Let us say the pipeline runs every 10 minutes. I want the pipeline in one iteration to persist the value so that it can be used in the next iteration.

Comment: They can't persist inside ADF across pipeline runs. If you really need something persistent, you're going to need to write data to a storage mechanism and then read it in subsequent pipelines. IMO, @Harris-Xu recommended the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joel Cochran says, ADF doesn't  support persist a variable inside pipeline runs. We need to write data to a storage, eg. database or azure storage. Use [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to get the value from blob storage file or DB. :)

Comment: Yes that is what I was already doing. But was expecting ADF to at least have such basic facility.

Comment: Sorry, per my experience, there is no other way now. :(